# Find Windows error in Event Viewer

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer, events

I am pretty new to Windows administration, however I need to learn fast. I received the following error while trying to diagnose a network interface.

```
"An unexpected error has occurred. The troubleshooting wizard can't continue"

Package ID: NetworkDiagnostics
Path: C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\networking
Error code: 0x80070057
Source: Engine
User: XXXXXXX
Context: Standard
```

My question is, is there a way I can use Event Viewer to find more information about why this occurred so I can further troubleshoot? Maybe search by the Error Code number?

Comment: If you want to know what the error code means, Google is your friend. :) Otherwise, no, there's no "hidden" event errors that will tell you "why" something happened.  You'll have to put on your new Admin hat and start researching, and correlating.  My guess would be that most likely the Network Diagnostics/Troubleshooter is failing for the same reason you're running it.  You have faulty hardware, or drivers, or...

Comment: Not to sound rude or anything, but Event Viewer is an Administrator Tool! I find it absurd that I must google error messages that pop up in the system, when some sort of logging process should be taking care of it. Why does Event Viewer even exist? This is why everyone is moving to Linux.

Comment: "Everyone is moving to linux". Oh really...?

Comment: Perhaps if you clarify exactly what additional "information" you expect the Event Log to provide, that may make it possible for us to point you in a direction. If all you want a local program that tells you information about the hex code errors, search around MS' site for "err.exe".

Answer (score 0):

This particular error seems to be a function of a bug in W10. It occurred regularly about a month ago, but seems to have stopped. Verify that you are up to date on W10 updates. Letting it search for solutions and fix the problem temporarily fixed it about 30% of the time. Other times a reboot, and sometimes just running the program again.
The EVENT VIEWER mostly gives you error codes, which you have to Google. I find it more expedient to just Google the original error verbage. I use event viewer when things happen and errors are not expressed.

+